# How to display hexadecimal bytes using NSLog

Tags: objective-c, byte, nslog

How can I display the following bytes using **NSLog**?

```
const void *devTokenBytes = [devToken bytes];
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming that `devToken` is of type `NSData *` (from the `bytes` call), you can use the `description` method on NSData to get a string containing the hexadecimal representation of the data's bytes. See the [NSData class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
NSLog(@"bytes in hex: %@", [devToken description]);
```

Comment: but now im getting the error message "warning: passing argument 1 of 'NSLog' from incompatible pointer type"

Comment: Because there's an error in the above code. He left off the @ infront of the string literal. i.e., NSLog("...") instead of NSLog(@"...").

Comment: jer, Chuck: thanks for pointing out and fixing, respectively. Too much C for me lately...

Comment: Curious, when I output the hex value, it comes wrapped with `<` and `>`. How do I get rid of that?

Answer (score 9):

If you want a hex sequence:

```
NSMutableString *hex = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[devToken length]];
for (int i=0; i < [devToken length]; i++) {
  [hex appendFormat:@"%02x", [devToken bytes][i]];
}
```

Comment: (!) `Argument type 'const void' is incomplete`